# Why an infinite loop makes a program non-responsive?

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

In a windows desktop application (windows forms), I've created a while loop in (c#):

```
bool stop = false;
while (!stop){    
...
// code to update a label that displays the number of times the loop executed.
...
}
```

When a button is clicked, "stop" is made true and the loop will stop.
However, I don't get the chance to click the button after the application runs because it becomes unresponsive.

that's one thing. 
The other thing that puzzles me more is why the label is not showing the number of loops. It's like the program is just looping and doing nothing.

If you are wondering, I'm trying to write code for a game loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows applications work by responding to Windows messages.
All WinForms events actually come from Windows messages like WM_PAINT or WM_MOSUEMOVE.

The .Net Framework's `Application` class runs a message loop which asks Windows for the next message, then processes the message as appropriate.

For example, if the user clicks a button, Windows sends your program a WM_CLICK message.  .Net's message loop converts this into a `Click` event and runs any event handlers that you registered.
While your code is running, the application is busy responding to whatever message it received, and it cannot respond to messages.
Therefore, it appears frozen.

You should replace your loop with a `Timer` component.
Move the loop body into the `Tick` handler and set the `Interval` to something like `20` or `50`.

Comment: To make it work: place the infinite loop in a separate thread.

Comment: @Time: Use a (WinForms) Timer.

Comment: @SLaks silly. Very silly that this is **the way**. Now I hate C# even more than I ever did before…

Comment: @Time: Why? What other option could make sense?

Comment: Thanks. It's also the same with WPF, so I guess it's the same reason.                                                             But why the label/Textblock is not being updated with the Number of loops. the update code is inside the loop and it is:                                                        textBlock1.Text = (NuOfFrames / timePassed).ToString();              Where NuOFrames is integer and timePassed is double?????    I initialized the textBlock's Text property with "FramesPerSecond" string literal and it's not overwritten after the loop starts?

Comment: @Saleh: Because the form can't paint itself until your loop finishes.